# JVM_SetNativeThreadName could not be located in the dynamic link library jvm.dll

Tags: eclipse, jvm

I started to get this error while launching eclipse:

The procedure entry point JVM_SetNativeThreadName could not be located in the dynamic link library jvm.dll

I reinstalled jre and set the classpath and then reinstalled eclipse but to no avail.

Kindly guide me through this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it might be this https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7116189, in which case I'd suggest trying JVM 7u4 or later (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/7u4bugfixes-1579555.html).

[followup]

I stumbled on this problem with my own (not eclipse's) native launcher based on the Janel project.  My particular case was caused by a bad-uninstall leaving jre/client/jvm.dll behind.  This particular jvm.dll didn't have the JVM_SetNativeThreadName, though jre/server/jvm.dll did.  The solution was to remove the old client directory and use the server jvm.dll.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was quite easy to solve:

In my "PATH" variable was only listed the jre not jdk path. After adding this it worked fine again.